# How to change the title text on the sale email?

Tags: magento-1.8, email, sales, sales-order

How can I change the title text on the sale email?

I always get this in my email when I make an order,

```
Main Website Store: New Order # 100000016
```

I want to change it to,

```
[Name of my Store]: New Order # 100000016
```

Is it possible? where can I change it?

Also, in the sale email content,

> Thank you for your order from Main Website Store. Once your package
>   ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. If you
>   have any questions about your order please contact us at
>   support@example.com or call us at Monday - Friday, 8am - 5pm PST.
>
> Your order confirmation is below. Thank you again for your business.

Where can I change all this? Especially `Main Website Store`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not change the files** in app/locale, they would be overwritten by an update.

You should use **Transactional Emails**, here some documentation about it:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails

You can then set the subject to be:
`{{var store.getFrontendName()}}: New Order #{{var order.increment_id}}`

Comment: I'm on Mangento Community edition, do I have Transactional Emails in this edition. the docu is for Magento Go.

Comment: Yes Transactional Emails is also in both Enterprise & Community. Go to System > Transactional Emails

Answer (score 5):

Magento manged store name from

```
admin>System >Configuration> General > Store information
```

also `{{var store.getFrontendName()}}` is provide store name of current store

and 
Goto  for register customer

```
app/locale/yourlanguage/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

and for guest customer

```
  app/locale/yourlanguage/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html
```

and changed in template file

```
{{var store.getFrontendName()}}: New Order # {{var order.increment_id}}
```

Comment: This is what I need. thanks @Amit Bera

Comment: @Amit Bera, please specify where to accomplish the same in Magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in the admin under System => Manage Stores. Change the name of the store to whatever you need.

Comment: please specify where to accomplish the same in Magento 2.3.4

Comment: In Magento 2.4.2 it's in Stores > All stores